# Db2 Backup Parallelims

Tags: server, db2, cluster-computing

I have a Paralellims log as follows.

Parallelism       = 5

```
Number of buffers = 10
Buffer size       = 16781312 (4097 4kB pages)
                                                                               Compr 
BM#    Total      I/O      Compr     MsgQ      WaitQ      Buffers   MBytes    MBytes 
---  --------  --------  --------  --------  --------    --------  --------  --------
000  52736.16  20487.24  17436.32      0.55    114.75       11508   1657254    833027       109
001  52736.15      0.00    151.29      0.00  45607.78         152         0      4833         0
002  52609.05   2337.31    372.99      0.00  43056.98         162    270010      8324         1
003  52618.25      5.46    180.66      0.00  45596.61          54       624      1922         0
004  52608.91      0.00    151.92      0.00  45607.77         159         0      5200         0
---  --------  --------  --------  --------  --------    --------  --------  --------
TOT  263308.54  22830.02  18293.20      0.56  179983.91       12035   1927888    853308

MC#    Total      I/O                MsgQ      WaitQ      Buffers   MBytes 
---  --------  --------            --------  --------    --------  --------
000  52736.23    903.91            51831.78      0.00       12036    192591
---  --------  --------            --------  --------    --------  --------
TOT  52736.23    903.91            51831.78      0.00       12036    192591
```

Is this reasonable? I have 15TB of data and it lasts for 15 hours for full backup and 8 hours for incremental. I using Db2 Purescale.

Thanks.

I want to increase the number of buffers but I don't know what impact it has into the database `your text`

Comment: This is not a programming question, it is an administration question. So you could move it to dba.stackexchange.com.  Also you should improve your question to show details of the target device(s) for the backup and what parallellism you have available there.

Comment: There is no reason to play with backup parallelism here. According to the statistics you have one large tablespace, and all other tablespaces are much smaller. Db2 still can't assign multiple db2bm processes to process the same tablespace simultaneously afaik. So, the only way to speedup your backup is to play with the DB2_PARALLEL_IO registry variable (db2stop/db2start is required to make changes take an effect).